# jQuery - cycle help

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I'm looking to get some help on using the [cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) library for jQuery. I'm in the [beginner](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/begin.html) demos, and I got the absolute first one completed. This is the second one on the page.

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pics').cycle({
        fx:      'scrollDown',
        speed:    300,
        timeout:  2000
    });
</script>
```

My CSS is identical to the one on the page, that's why I put .pics in the quotes.

Comment: It would help us if you told us what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

I will take a guess that this is just not working for you. You need to balance your braces and parentheses.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.pics').cycle({  
        fx: 'scrollDown',     
        speed: 300,     
        timeout: 2000 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK to re-open this question? It's working OK but I'm having a rough time styling this. I'm trying to make images float left, and text wrap around it to the right like in the [demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html) (non image content).

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text')
    .before('<div id="slidenav">')
    .cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'slow',
        timeout: 6000,
        pager:  '#slidenav',
       pause: 1
    });
});

</script>
```

...

```
<div id="featured">
    <div class="text">
        <txp:article_custom form="slidetext" section="slide" limit="5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS is:

```
.text { width: 600px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: green; }
.text div { width: 500px; height: 200px; padding: 15px; color: #333; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; background-color:red; }
.text div img {width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 3px; background: orange }
.text div p{ background-color:black;}
```

Sorry there is no float properties here, because none of them were working. I grabbed that CSS off the jQuery cycle demo page.

And the outcome is

[http://img147.imageshack.us/img147/4434/jqueryhelpdl5.jpg http://img147.imageshack.us/img147/4434/jqueryhelpdl5.jpg](http://img147.imageshack.us/img147/4434/jqueryhelpdl5.jpg)

http://img147.imageshack.us/img147/4434/jqueryhelpdl5.jpg